# how to get x most recent records from two tables at once

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite

I have two tables: one for posts and one for topics:

```
posts: id, topic_id, content, created_at, updated_at 
topics: id, title, content, created_at, updated_at
```

I want to retrieve x most recent records from both of them based on updated_at column. So in the end I expect to have them in ONE collection consisted of BOTH Post and Topic type objects. I hope I made myself clear.

Comment: Are the tables related by topic_id on posts and id on topics?

Comment: Yes, topic has many posts. post.topic_id references topic.id

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I haven't made myself clear enough in the end. But in meantime I came up with solution. It's not perfect but it works.

```
  def recent_activities(count: 10)
    posts  = Post.order(updated_at: :desc).limit(count)
    topics = Topic.order(updated_at: :desc).limit(count)
    activities = posts + topics
    activities.sort! { |x, y| y.updated_at <=> x.updated_at }
    activities.first(count)
  end
```

So, as you can see post.topic_id and topic.id association is not relevant. There are two tables which just happens to both have updated_at columns. I need recent X records from group consisted of posts and topics - in snipped above called activities.

Answer (score -1):

since you already have the associations, why not just:

```
<% Topic.order(:created_at => :asc).limit(10) do |topic| %>
  <%= topic.title %>
  <%= topic.content %>
  <%= topic.post.content %>
  <%= topic.created_at %>
  <%= topic.post.created_at %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You have to decide whether to order by when the topic was created or when the post was created; you cannot order on both values